# Firebase, Fetch data under child "user"

Tags: html, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I´m making a order placement app, and I´m trying to display the data on a website. The app who produces the data is iOS - Swift 3, and the website that's going to show the data is html. 
Truble is that I can´t get past the randomly generated userId. I want all data under the userId to be displayed when the "Order" child is changed. The Firebase looks like this:

[Screenshot firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqa7I.png)

Comment: Please specify a programming language. because firebase supports different platforms and languages. how ever you can check 
for change Listening : firebaseNodeRed.addValueEventListener
and for Iterating all values under a child : childRef
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention language. Updated post. Thank you for your answer